# How do I require login authentication to access the Vault UI console on port 8500?

Tags: authentication, ldap, consul, hashicorp-vault

Can we provide login authentication to vault UI?

What are the most popular and methods available to achieve login authentication?

Comment: // , For an example environment that automates login restrictions on both Vault and Consul, check out the following repository: https://github.com/v6/super-duper-vault-train I need testers!

Comment: // , Please improve your question. http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#intro

Answer (score 1):

8500 is the default port for Consul, not Vault.

Are you sure it's not Consul?

For reference, here are the default UIs for Consul and Vault, respectively:

Consul (Port 8500)
[image]

Vault (Port 8200)
[image]

Please add more details, because it looks like you're asking about **[Consul ACLs](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/acl.html)**, not Vault UI access stuff.

Comment: Bananese . Sorry for the confusion here. It is consul UI. Consul UI is access directly without any authentication.any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Cosul does not provide authentication, I have a nginx siting in front of consul, basic auth happens at nignx and then it proxy pass the traffic to consul.